# error called to undifined method when using pop()

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm trying to add the pop function to a button in flex 4. But I keep getting an error call to undefined method when I try to use it, but it's a built in function isn't it? I posted my code below, any ideas?

```
    <s:Button x="405" y="410" label="Undo last" width="85" click="data.pop()" id="undo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.pop()` most likely won't work unless you are using your button as item renderer or item editor in a DataGrid.

In case you defined a variable of type `Array` called `data` try to rename it to something else. `data` is used by the framework itself.

Comment: Well I tried changing the name, still getting the same error. Even put it into an even listener, same out come.

Comment: Could you please post a larger, working example that shows what you are doing?